# How to Add route links to material ui tabs in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I'm using ts in react. How to add the route links to the tabs in my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: any;
  value: any;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: any) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to make the links like /home/item1, /home/item2 and so on.

How to add this in typescript of react. Navigating on tabs should update the url on browser address bar.
Or if the user hits directly /home/item2, it should open that tab by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Tab` to render as a `Link` using the `component` prop like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

...

<Tab
  ...
  component={Link}
  to="/home/item1"
/>
```

Note, it also passes through any other non-Tab props to `component`, so you can specify the `to` prop of the `Link` or any others you need to set.

To set the selected tab from the route, figure out the appropriate index from the location (you can get this from `useLocation`) and init the `value` state with that index instead of hardcoding to `0`:

```
const location = useLocation()
const selectedIndex = figureOutSelectedIndex(location)

const [value, setValue] = React.useState(selectedIndex);
```